# how to access a variable from outside the $scope function angular javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to access the variable "k" from out side the $scope function

```
  .controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
  var k ="";
  $scope.search = function() {
    // $scope.searchText will give the search terms
    k = $scope.searchText;
    console.log(k); //has something
  };
  console.log(k); // this is empty
```

Comment: This is looks pretty good..  First when you initiate the controller K will empty.. then once method is invoked k will hold the value

Comment: `k = $scope.searchText` this statement is  bound to the block scope of  function expression `$scope.search`, hence it would not work on initial load.

Comment: And how do you think it should work?

Comment: @AlexanderAnikeev: well in this case, it doesnt make sense to read the `searchText` value before its definition. also it depends on why this flow is required in the app

Comment: @dreamweiver sorry, the comment was addressed to the author. I agree with your comment "it would not work on initial load"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $rootScope for this, rootScope is a globle variable in angular, you need to just inject dependency as you can see in below code and use it outside controller as well..

```
.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$rootScope'  function($scope,$http,$rootScope) {
     // var k =""; use below method.
    $rootScope.k = "";
      $scope.search = function() {
        // $scope.searchText will give the search terms
        $rootScope.k = $scope.searchText;
        console.log($rootScope.k); //has something
      };
      console.log($rootScope.k); // this is empty
```

Comment: i got it to work using this thanks! i used (.run) and it works

Answer (score 1):

It will be empty until you really call `search`  function,

```
app.controller("AboutCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  var k = "";
  $scope.search = function() {
    // $scope.searchText will give the search terms
    k = $scope.searchText;
    console.log(k); //has something
  };
  //this will print the value
  $scope.print = function() {
    alert(k);
  }

});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qg99qm87dELV89fbN4ZP?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular's services. Basically you need to create the service as below

```
app.service('svc', function() {
  this.k = "";
  this.setK = function(value) {
    this.k = value;
  }
  this.getK = function() {
    return this.k;
  }
});
```

Then make sure to inject the service to your controller

```
.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http,svc) {
  var k ="";
  $scope.search = function() {
    // $scope.searchText will give the search terms
    k = $scope.searchText;
    console.log(k); //has something
    svc.setK(k);  //saving k to the service
  };
  console.log(k); // this is empty
  k = getK();  //getting k from the service
```